# Enabling Exceptions in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm attempting to debug my Azure Function App, all I get is "An error has occurred" which is making fixing my issues extremely difficult.  Any idea how to enable full exceptions to be returned by the application?  Anything to make debugging possible as I'm massively blocked by this right now.

Many thanks.

Nick.

Edit:  In the table storage log for the function I see the following error,

```
...obs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.<Invoke>d__29.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`1.<InvokeAsync>d__8.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<InvokeAsync>d__22.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__21.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__19.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__13.MoveNext()   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I see this error even if I manually throw an exception on the first line.  Where is the real exception?

[image]
Looking at these logs really makes me question Microsoft's decisions at times, how is this useful to anyone? Or am I missing something crucial here?

Comment: you can log anything you want,, including exceptions. also, if you use visual studio you can install azure function tools and debug https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/12/01/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions/

Comment: Hi there, sorry could you please give more information, what do you mean I can log anything I want?  How, I can't get anything except "An error has occurred" to get returned, and that Kodu log is no more helpful, giving some obscure Async winding exception.  I have the tools installed, but they won't even run locally, I require Facebook authentication for my function and there seems to be no way to set that up locally using the tools.

Comment: the quickstart examples show how to log. you can then see the logs in the function console or on the monitoring section.  Logging is different than what is returned.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I want, I don't want to manually log messages, I want the return value of the function to return the actual exception and not "an error has occurred".  You can't even use try catch blocks to get most errors, it just ignores them and throws this generic error.

Comment: If I look in table storage for the function logs, all I see is this,  even if I throw an exception on the first line of the function, the error is always the same,

Comment: I'll write it as an edit..

Comment: Nick, try catches definitely work and give you the ability to fully handle the exceptions however you want (log, return error, etc.) are you perhaps kicking off some asynchronous work and ignoring the retuned Task/result? Can you share a the repro you've mentioned above?

Comment: Okay I can get exception handling to work in something simple but I think the issue here is that the entire UI fails to work properly when you have authentication enabled.  You can no longer test or see compiler issues in the browser.  How do I fix this?

Comment: After disabling facebook authentication, not only do I get no compilation messages in the UI still, but the method will not even run with a test, resulting in a 404 error.  This is a nightmare to develop with.

Comment: Okay, it's now working again, will write above what I've done to fix it.

Comment: @Nick you should write what you've done as an answer instead of on your question

Comment: Okay no probs, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so this is my solution, this may vary depending on what's wrong for you as the error is so generic.  Firstly what I done was disable authentication for my function to try to get the in-browser compiler to work again as this has been broken ever since I done this, it didn't help, it resulted in 404 errors for all of my functions.  So I enabled it again, this caused the compiler to start working!  It showed that I had a reference mismatch for Azure Storage, somehow my dll was referencing 7.x but was expecting 6.x in the function app, which is odd as I don't recall ever changing it.  Anyway, I created a **project.json** file with the following in,

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.2.1"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

After uploading this to the folder of each function, it works again.  I will now explicitly set all of my external dependencies via a **project.json** file to hopefully prevent this from happening again.

> It's worth noting that although this doesn't make the full exception
>   get returned in-browser, it did enable me to see compiler errors,
>   which is what was causing the issue and preventing me from handling
>   any exceptions in the function app.

-

> One last note and to show how buggy Azure Function Apps are, even
>   though Authentication is "enabled" according to the app settings, it's
>   not working, this is why the in-browser compiler is now working.  I'm
>   working on getting it working again, but won't be replying to this
>   thread anymore.  Just be wary.